# B2 visa: not allowed for biometrics due to wrong passport number in appointment confirmation page. Is that visa application considered rejected?

Tags: visas, usa, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

My father had an appointment for biometrics today for his United States B2 visa, but was not allowed inside, as the passport number in the appointment confirmation was wrong.  (I made the mistake of using my own number, due to computer problems).

The application fee has been paid to the Embassy with his correct application number, and got a barcode with his application number. Also, the DS-160 has his correct passport number and application number.

The only problem was a wrong passport number in the appointment confirmation, which we did not notice until he went to the interview. He tried going to the office, showing DS_160 confirmation page, his original passport, visa fee receipt and other documents but he was not allowed for biometrics. But with the same application they **allowed my mother to get biometrics** as we **booked their appointment together** (my mother's name and passport number were not shown in the appointment confirmation page, as the appointment was booked with my father's name. Yet she was allowed as they checked only her DS-160 confirmation page and passport). We'll see what happens to her consular interview tomorrow.
now

1. What should I do with my father's visa application?
2. Is my father's visa application considered rejected?
3. Should I pay the visa fee again to book an appointment for my father again?
4. In the website my father's consular appointment is marked cancelled but no option to reschedule but there is option to schedule new appointment.
5. If I try to book a new appointment for my father, it is still taking my passport number in appointment details and it's not possible to edit anywhere while booking appointment on website.
6. If I have to reapply for my father's B2 visa, how long until I should apply?
7. Should I fill a DS-160 again to book an appointment again ?
8. What should he fill for the question "Have you ever been rejected with B2 visa?" in his next application or interview?

Please clarify the above issues if anyone has any experience with this. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Someone has voted to close this as too broad.  While the body of the question does contain many different questions, they're essentially detailed aspects of the single question, "what can we do now?"  If the question were truly too broad, it would make sense to break it up and repost it as several separate questions, but I don't see how that would make sense.

Comment: Happened to a friend of mine. There is a number/email address for visa applications you can contact. They will work with you to open up the application so you can make the change, or they can do it for you. They will verify your identity through some security question before. They are not the easiest to reach however in a couple of days you should be hearing back from them.

Comment: @user56513 love it, they are not the easiest to reach, that’s the same with all visa/passport matters I think, Swedish consulate in Shanghai is open every other Monday 9-9:30 if it doesn’t rain in Dubai I feel sometimes

Comment: Well, it doesn't rain that much in Dubai.

Comment: His application would be rejected, not refused. In other words it never got to a stage where someone looked at it and refused it. So the only good thing is that if you are asked "have you ever been refused a visa", this one doesn't count.

Answer (score 4):

#### Q: What should I do with my father's visa application?

#### Q: Should I fill a DS-160 again to book an appointment again ?

#### Q: If I have to reapply for my father's B2 visa, how long until I should apply?

Unfortunately, [it is not possible to amend a submitted DS-160 application form](https://jp.usembassy.gov/visas/nonimmigrant-visas/ds160/retrieve-recover-form/). The only option you have is to compile a new application form:

> [image: Immihelp edit ds160 application]

Therefore, your father will have to compile a new DS-160 making sure the data is correct. I would do this as soon as possible to make some progress on your father's application.

#### Q: Is my father's visa application considered rejected?

#### Q: What should he fill for the question "Have you ever been rejected with B2 visa?" in his next application or interview?

I do not think that the application is rejected nor refused because no evaluation on eligibility was made. Your father's application was basically denied since it contained erroneous information. Therefore, he should answer "No".

#### Q: Should I pay the visa fee again to book an appointment for my father again?

It depends on what is asked at the end of the application process. [This answer on Quora suggests that you should not have to pay again](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-edit-information-on-a-DS-160-form-after-having-booked-the-appointment-and-paid-the-visa-fee):

> Note: You do not have to pay the application fees again if you do this.
>
> - Log in to [Nonimmigrant Visa - Instructions Page](https://ceac.state.gov/GenNIV/Default.aspx) and retrieve your EXISTING APPLICATION. The cash you paid already will not be refunded, so just edit using the same application number
> - You will get the following message on the screen:
>
> > The DS-160 application you are attempting to retrieve has been submitted. Select an option below and click the "Continue" button.
> >
> > - View Confirmation Page
> > - Create a New Application
>
> [image: ds application file a new one]
>
> - Select the option: “Create a New Application” and click “Continue”
> - A new DS 160 application number will be generated and that will be your new number for attending the interview.
> - Make necessary changes that you were planning to. Please note: While most of your details would be available in the new form as well, some data wouldn’t be retrieved and you will have to enter them manually again. Especially, the security questions towards the end.
> - Once the errors are corrected, submit the new DS 160 form.
> - You will receive new U.S. DoS - CEAC Confirmation. Take its print out.
>
> Next is an IMPORTANT step
>
> - Log in to the website [https://cgifederal.secure.force....](https://cgifederal.secure.force.com/) where you have taken an appointment for bio metrics and interview.
> - Update your profile there with the new DS 160 application number.
> - Submit
> - You will get a new appointment confirmation with the new application number.
>
> Carry both the new DS 160 form and appointment confirmation for the bio metrics session and interview. No need to carry the ones with the old application number as their system will be updated with the new number.

#### Q: In the website my father's consular appointment is marked cancelled but no option to reschedule but there is option to schedule new appointment.

#### Q: If I try to book a new appointment for my father, it is still taking my passport number in appointment details and it's not possible to edit anywhere while booking appointment on website.

For these specific questions, if the steps mentioned above do not work, I would directly contact the embassy which handled your case and seek their help.